# Newton square root method

Tags: java

we have a class call newton where we use newton's method of square root. Here is the code which I came up with. We have to use recursion, to find the answer. This is the formula we have to use to find the answer, 
 Xn = (Xn-1 - (Xn-1)^2 - k) / 2(Xn1).   Xn = the new guess or the variable t.  Xn-1 = the users guess or the g. K  = the number that is being squared. This  method will keep doing until the new guess the t is equal to the answer. SO my question is does this look right?

```
class Newton {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double k = 25; // number that is being squarted
    double g = 10; // number we are quessing
    double x = 0; // x holds the answers 
    x = Math.sqrt(k);
    System.out.print(x);
    int answer= find(t);
   System.out.println("The square root is " + answer);
}
public static int find(double k, double g, double x, double t){
    if (g == x){

    } return g;
    else{
        t = (x - 1) - (Math.pow(x - 1, 2) - k) / (2 * (x - 1));
        g = t;
    } return (int) t;
}
```

}

Comment: I see statements and code, but no where is there a straightforward easily understandable question. Please fix this by asking a direct question for us to help you answer. Also tell us: what is this code doing that you don't want it to do? What is it not doing that you want it to do? Details will help greatly.

Comment: You are not even calling the find-method, so I don't see how it could work. Then double-parameters are passed by value and not reference.

Comment: This is not a code review site.

Answer (score 1):

Try to correct the return statement like this:

```
  public static int find(double k, double g, double x, double t){
    if (g == x){
        return (int) g;
    }
    else{
        t = (x - 1) - (Math.pow(x - 1, 2) - k) / (2 * (x - 1));
        g = t;
     return (int) t;
    } 
}
```

You have `int` return not `double` and there place was wrong.